# Difference between putting WCF namespace or not?

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf

I was following this [tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb924552%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), and also came across this [article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms732002%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) after I finished the previous tutorial.

What makes me wonder is the `[ServiceContractAttribute]` . I saw the `[ServiceContract]` in the article does not have Namespace, but the tutorial has one.

So I went ahead and changed `[ServiceContract(Namespace="SandwichServices")]` into `[ServiceContract]`, but when I run the application and click the button, I get an exception: `Uncaught ReferenceError: SandwichServices is not defined`.

So I would like to know,

1. Is there any way to resolve this error other than revert the changes? Maybe Web.config is the answer but I'm not sure I'm on the right track.
2. What is the difference between two `[ServiceContractAttribute]`? From my perspective, looks like `Namespace` is not required for interfaces, but am I right?

Web.config file contents:

```xml
<system.serviceModel>
  <behaviors>
    <endpointBehaviors>
      <behavior name="SandwichServices.CostServiceAspNetAjaxBehavior">
        <enableWebScript />
      </behavior>
    </endpointBehaviors>
  </behaviors>

  <serviceHostingEnvironment
      aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" 
      multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />

  <services>
    <service name="SandwichServices.CostService">
      <endpoint address="" 
          behaviorConfiguration="SandwichServices.CostServiceAspNetAjaxBehavior" 
          binding="webHttpBinding"
          contract="SandwichServices.CostService" />
    </service>
  </services>
</system.serviceModel>
```

Comment: To answer first question, can you add your web.config to question and it is likely a configuration issue.

Comment: Did you update your service reference?

Comment: @PeterB, sorry, tried to add part of the Web.config, but am having issue with formatting the code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are correct, the namespace property of the ServiceContractAttribute is not required in your contract definition, but it defaults to "http://tempuri.org". This is used to define the namespace of the port type in the WSDL. It is unclear from your question why the error is occurring.

It is good practice (particularly for externally facing APIs) to use a non-default namespace in urn format (e.g., urn:companyname:servicename). Additionally, you can use the Name property to further define the service.

Example:

For a menu service

```
[ServiceContract(Name="menu", Namespace="urn:subway:sandwich")]
```

For an order service

```
[ServiceContract(Name="order", Namespace="urn:subway:sandwich")]
```

etc.

And typically, you would match the WSDL namespace to the CLR namespace in your code.

To conintue the example:

```
namespace Subway.Sandwich
{
   [ServiceContract(Name="menu", Namespace="urn:subway:sandwich")]
   public interface MenuService
   {

   }

   [ServiceContract(Name="order", Namespace="urn:subway:sandwich")]
   public interface OrderService
   {

   }
}
```

To answer your specific questions.

1. Not enough information in question to know (but likely issue with configuration).
2. ServiceContract and ServiceContractAttribute are the same and namespace is not required.

Comment: If you admit yourself that you cannot answer the question, then you should first post a comment asking for clarification. After gathering required information post a complete answer.

Comment: @BartoszKP thanks -- I'm new here and will update accordingly

Comment: No worries, that's a very nice answer - the only problem is that it misses the point. But as soon as OP will update the question with relevant details and you'll add a particular solution for OP's problem it'll be OK :)

Answer (score 1):

Regarding this particular tutorial, in my case it was sufficient (after removing the namespace from the `ServiceContractAttribute`) to change the line:

```
var service = new SandwichServices.CostService();
```

to

```
var service = new CostService();
```

in the Javascript part. Everything works again.

You can find more explanations in [PeterB's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23136447/2642204).

Comment: It is weird. I tried your method but it doesn't work. Still having error when I clicked the button.

Comment: @TanJiaMing Have you tried "Rebuild"? I really just literally repeated your steps: 1) version from the tutorial (works) 2) removing namespace (stops working) 3) fixing JS (starts working again)

Comment: Yup, I even tried "Clean", and went a little more extreme by deleting the DLL manually, but still no luck.

Answer (score 1):

I also tend to think that you just forgot to update your service reference for the client application after changing the namespace. It works pretty much the same as for .NET classes. Let's consider an example. You have a class named `SuperClass` in the namespace `MyProject.SuperClasses`. You already use the class somewhere in the code and then you go and change the namespace for the class. You will most likely get a build error and will have to add using statment for the new namespace.

Also a couple of real life examples why you should specify namespaces:

1.

> You should always specify the name and namespace of your data contract
>   to prevent your .NET type’s name and namespace from being exposed in
>   the contract. This way, if you decide later to change the .NET
>   namespace or type name, your data contract remains the same.

In simple words, with namespaces specified, you will not break existing clients if you decide to do some refactoring and rename a class or property.

2.

Namespaces are often used for versioning WCF services. I would even say it's a best practice to use namespaces to version a WCF service. So you should design your namespaces carefully and include versioning info into them like that:

```
http://schemas.contoso.com/2005/05/21/PurchaseOrder
```

This will simplify things greatly for you in the future when you want to make changes to your contracts and make sure that existing clients will not break. You can read up more on the topic [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733832%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Hope it helps!

Comment: Sorry but I'm fairly new to WCF. Can I know how should I update my service reference regarding this particular case?

Comment: @Tan Jia Ming Go to the client application project, expand service reference folder, right click the reference and there will be a menu item to update the reference.